# Hidden classes and equivalence between {} object vs. custom constructor (v8)

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

Given this article:

http://richardartoul.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/04/26/hidden-classes.html

If you create a constructor such as:

```
function Point(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

Then doing this:

```
var obj1 = new Point(1,2);
var obj2 = new Point(3,4);

obj1.a = 5;
obj1.b = 10;

obj2.b = 10;
obj2.a = 5;
```

means you get some sort of performance optimizations under the hood.

I'm wondering though, if you just do this instead:

```
var obj1 = { a: 5, b: 10 }
var obj2 = { b: 10, a: 5 }
```

Will you get the same performance optimizations if you follow that pattern for thousands of objects, or is a new hidden class created for each `var objn` instance.

Basically wondering if it's required to use a constructor function to get this performance optimization.

Comment: You don't get any performance optimization in both cases (I guess you meant prototypes, but you don't use them). Prefer second way.

Comment: As the article concludes: "*Always instantiate your object properties in the same order*" (so that they get the same hidden class). `obj1` and `obj2` are different from each other in *both* of your examples.

Comment: dfsq: Not sure what you're talking about; of course V8 will apply whatever optimizations it can in both cases; assigning all properties in a constructor is (generally) faster because it avoids polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the article says in its summary:

> Always instantiate your object properties in the same order so that hidden classes, and subsequently optimized code, can be shared.

In your alternative example `var obj1 = { a: 5, b: 10 }; var obj2 = { b: 10, a: 5 }`, the properties are clearly not added in the same order, so the hidden classes cannot be shared.

You don't have to use a constructor *per se*, but using a constructor is the easiest way to ensure that you're getting the performance you want. (It is also generally considered ergonomic and good coding practice.)

Comment: Using a factory function, like `function create(a, b) { return {a, b}; }` (to be called as `create(5, 10)`) would also ensure that properties are always created in the same order