# How v8 stores fast objects

Tags: javascript, v8

As a follow-up question to the answer to [If v8 rehashes when an object grows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011721/if-v8-rehashes-when-an-object-grows/50011783#50011783), I am wondering how v8 actually stores "fast" objects.

From the answer:

> Fast mode is typically much faster for property access - but requires the object's structure to be known.
>
> V8 will initially try to construct a template of what the object looks like called a "Hidden Class". The object will transform through hidden classes until V8 will give up and store the object as a slow property.

Then I asked if v8 *rehashes* when an object grows, and the answer was:

> there is no hashing at all - it's just an offset of memory access - like a struct in C.

(for fast mode objects)

It also mentions:

> objects aren't stored as hash maps at all in this case - it's a hidden class

So to summarize, even though you change the object properties, it is still structured so that there is a hidden class:

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
x.d = 4
x.e = 5
x.f = 6
```

Based on the answer, v8 doesn't actually use a hashtable to store the values because it instead uses a hidden class. So the question is, how does v8 actually store the values as a hidden class struct. What does the hidden class *do*, how is it structured, how does it work. When you later in your code do `var d = 'd'; x[d]` (just to make it dynamic), how does it know where the value for `d` is without hashing the `d` property as a string to get the index (theoretically). How does it find the memory address of the struct from the key.

Comment: Each time you modify the structure of the object, new hidden class will be created. Lets say we have const obj = {val:1}; Then hidden class will be created. If you do obj.val = 2, nothing will change. But if you do obj.newProp = "", then new hidden class will be created. That's why important to keep objects more less stable to reduce number of the hidden classes and help V8 deal with them.

Comment: @Vitalii I understand that part :) I don't understand how it's actually implemented to find the memory address of the keyed value though.

Comment: Do you mean: how to access hidden class having the plane object without any map and hashes?

Comment: No, I mean when you do `var d = 'd'; x[d]`, what happens under the hood. How does the C code interpret that code. That is, how does it find the value. The answer says the hidden class is a struct, so you can just jump to that place in memory. But how does it go from `var d = 'd'; x[d]` to the struct's place in memory.

Comment: @LancePollard i think it's more like a search in a linked list than a hash map

Comment: Have a look at https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html and https://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is no hashing at all - it's just an offset of memory access - like a struct in C.

A struct in C is a continuously block of data. The properties are stored at a fixed offset away from the struct pointer.

For example in

```
type Foo struct {
  x int32
  y int32
}
```

If the memory address of `foo` is `m`, the memory address of `foo.x` and `foo.y` will be `m+4`, `m+8`, respectively. Hashtable is not needed here.

V8 maps `foo.x` to a fixed offset at compile time.

For dynamic properties access the above does not apply.